# Write subquery to compare list in JPA Criteria

Tags: java, subquery, spring-data-jpa, jpa-criteria

I have the following entity structure:

```
class A {
    int aId;
    B b;
}

class B {
    int bId;
    C c;
}

class C {
    List<B> bs;
    int cId;
}
```

I have to write the following part of SQL code using spring-data-jpa specifications:

`SELECT * FROM A WHERE ~~blahblahblah~~ AND  **bId in (SELECT bs FROM C WHERE cId = myCId)**`

I tried to do like this:

```
Subquery<B> bSubquery = criteriaQuery.subquery(B.class);
Root<B> bRoot = bSubquery.from(B.class);
bSubquery.select(bRoot).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(bRoot.get(B.c).get(C.cId), myCId));
return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(A.b), root.in(bSubquery));
```

But it does't work. Where is my mistake?

Comment: CriteriaQuery etc is nothing to do with Spring or Spring Specification. It is JPA Criteria API; tags and title updated

Comment: @NeilStockton ok, thanks

Comment: can you post entire query and error which you got